# Autoupdating a Hosted Google Chrome Extension - No additiontal Headers sent with request

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Note: This is not a question, but instead a tip. Unless someone knows or a workaround?

If you are hosting your Google Chrome Extension on your own server and you have any type of authentication, be aware that the update check and .crx request will NOT send any additional headers. Depending on your authentication process, the Update and .crx requests may need to be public.

I feel this note should be added to the Autoupdating documentation here:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html

Knowing this in advance would have saved me a couple of hours debugging and googling, so I thought I'd share.